# Click on first onclick function inside tag by class selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm new here ... so let me know how I can click on the first onclick within this div . Note that if you do $ (".giornoweekcorrente" ) i select the entire interior of the div but my problem is, how do I get to click the function visualizzaEvento ... through the class " giornoweekcorrente " .

Take a look for this image to understand.

[image]

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please do not post screenshots and expect people to solve your problem by looking images and writing down the code in the image for test! Share the related part of your code by writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. Hope this helps.

```
$('.giornoweekcorrente a:first').click();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works! If i put :second work on second onclick or not? For coriousity. Thanks again!

Comment: Use `:nth-child(n)` where `n`is the number of the target child

Comment: @MarkusWerner :  You need to use `:nth-child(2)` for second. Read about it https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround:

```
// get the first anchor child of the element and trigger the desired event:
$('.giornoweekcorrente').on('click', function(){
    $('a', this).first().trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = $(".giornoweekcorrente").children()[0]
$(target).click(function(){
  visualizzaEvento();
});
```

just find the children of your div, and find the first child.

see : https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag has an **id** why not use that:

```
$("#lente_click_gio").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Markus, you might want to attach "onclick" to the element with id "lente_click_gio" directly. You can do that using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lente_click_gio").on('click',function(){
       //Your code here .. Call visualizzaEvento
    });
});
```

But this would just attach the click event and the callback to it. Instead if you want to trigger a click event on the anchor element where you have attached the function, try the following code:

```
$("#lente_click_gio").click(); /* Generate a click event on the element with the ID lente_click_gio */
```

This would trigger a click event on that element. Hope this would help.